# UIView Background Image and UITable View complications

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

I am having a strange issue with displaying a custom image in my UIView. I have a table view that is setup displaying 4 cells, and then behind that I would like to have a custom image. Right now it is looking like this:[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/48927630ba.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/48927630ba.jpg) 
where the tan is the background color I want, and the grayish color right next to the cells is the color I don't want. Here is my code in the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAGE320.tiff"]];
```

I know its a pretty basic problem, but why is that gray ish part showing up next to my cells? There has to be a way to clean that up...any help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
[myTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I may be putting that code snippwt in the wrong place, but that is just makin the whole screen go white now...any thoughts?

Comment: ok.if you created your tableView in the IB, then in the viewDidLoad: method you can set it's backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor]. it will work if you have some view as a main view and the UITableView as subView